# Google Cloud Module disappeared

Tags: android-studio, google-app-engine, objectify

After updating to Android Studio 3.0.1 I see there is no option to add a Google Cloud module, as you would to add a backend module for building endpoints using Objectify. Any tutorial tells you to add this module. Do we have to create it manually now or is there a completely different way to communicate with Appengine?

Answer (score 0):

You must use Cloud Tools for IntelliJ now:

https://cloud.google.com/tools/android-studio/docs/

https://cloud.google.com/tools/intellij/docs/

> Note: Creating App Engine-based cloud backends is not supported in Android Studio 3.0; however, your existing projects with cloud backends will continue to work in Android Studio.
>
> To create a new App Engine Java project, you can use either Cloud Tools for Intellij or Cloud Tools for Eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Does this mean Firebase is the default backend for a native Android app?